# Docker extend entrypoint script from docker-compose

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm very new to Docker.

I dockerized my Laravel application.
This is the base image `php:8.1.2-apache`

At the end of Dockerfile I'm using my own entrypoint script

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/start"]
```

This script (`/usr/local/bin/start`) contains few commands like

```sh
composer install --no-interaction && 
php artisan config:cache && 
php artisan route:cache && 
php artisan view:cache && 
php artisan storage:link
```

Now I'm using this Docker Image for many things like laravel scheduler, queue etc...

What I want to do is to extend the entrypoint script from docker-compose file, so that whenever the containers get started the entrypoint script gets executed first then finally the main command which will be passing from docker-compose will be executed.

Something like:

```
  laravel-scheduler:
    image: laravel
    container_name: laravel-scheduler
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    command: php artisan schedule:work
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

You can create build_entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

composer install --no-interaction && 
php artisan config:cache && 
php artisan route:cache && 
php artisan view:cache && 
php artisan storage:link
```

And use it `ENTRYPOINT ["./build_entrypoint.sh"]` in base Dockerfile

In docker-compose you can override the behavior: in command section start manually
`/build_entrypoint.sh` + extended commands

something like
`command: /bin/sh -c "./build_entrypoint.sh && ./test_running.sh"`

.

**Second: pretty**

Start a new service in docker-compose with your daemon based on the main php image.

*docker/php/Dockerfile*

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# ... others commands (setup composer and php-ext(s))

# Attention! We run this command to build our image
RUN composer install --no-interaction && 
  php artisan config:cache && 
  php artisan route:cache && 
  php artisan view:cache && 
  php artisan storage:link
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
# Main php service
php:
    build:
        context: docker/php    # path to your dockerfile
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html

# PHP WORKER service with daemon work
php-worker:
    build:
        context: docker/php    # path to your dockerfile
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
    command: php artisan schedule:work
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, just one thing, doing this: `command: /bin/sh -c "./build_entrypoint.sh && ./test_running.sh"` in docker-compose means the script files will be picked from the path relative to docker-compose file, and not from container's files. right?  
Thank you so much :)

Comment: hello, i'am add second solution

Answer (score 0):

Simply end the entrypoint script with `exec "$@"`.  It will honor the Compose `command:` in exactly the way you describe.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Do first-time setup steps that can't be done in the Dockerfile
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
php artisan storage:link

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

Also see [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the Dockerfile documentation: the `CMD` (or the Compose `command:` override) gets passed as arguments to your entrypoint script.  The `exec "$@"` invocation is a shell command to replace the current shell with those command-line arguments.

The one other important caveat is that, in the Dockerfile, `ENTRYPOINT` must be the JSON-array [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example).  If it's bare-string shell form, the shell wrapping prevents this from working.  The syntax you show in the question is correct.